# Installing .net 4 project on target server - Error System.BadImageFormatException

Tags: .net, .net-4.0

I have installed the .net 4 framework on one of my servers.

When I run an installation project created in Visual Studio - get the following error:

> Error 1001 Exception occurred while
>   initializing the installation.
>   System.BadImageFormatException: Could
>   not load file or assembly  or one of its
>   dependencies. This assembly is built
>   by a runtime newer than the currently
>   loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.

I've definately installed the .net 4 framework on the target machine - what's going on?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I eventually found the solution to this, and blogged about it: [Deploying .NET 4 Project – Error 1001 (System.BadImageFormatException)](http://www.alexjamesbrown.com/uncategorized/deploying-net-4-project-error-1001-system-badimageformatexception/)

---

**Update:** Copied the content from the [blog](http://www.alexjamesbrown.com/uncategorized/deploying-net-4-project-error-1001-system-badimageformatexception/):

"After attending the UK Tech Days events last week in London, I was keen to jump on the Visual Studio 2010 and .net 4.0 bandwagon.

I converted some of our projects here at Crocus to the .net 4 framework (which was incredibly easy – nothing broke!)
I even took advantage of some of the quick to implement features in .net 4, and converted some of our massively over-ridden methods to use optional parameters.

One project in particular is a Windows Service, that sends out purchase orders on a schedule.
(I recently wrote about how this broke due to Quartz.net expecting a UTC start time)

This has a Visual Studio deployment project associated with it.

After building the newly upgraded .net 4 version of the project, and deploying the .msi file to our target server, I got the following error:

> Error 1001 Exception occurred while initializing the installation.
>   System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly or one
>   of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than
>   the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.

Now, I had definitely upgraded said server to .net 4 (twice, as a matter of fact – after the first time i received this error!)

After some Googling, some people were saying to change the [platform target](http://visualstudiohacks.com/articles/visual-studio-net-platform-target-explained/) on my assemblies, which i did, to no avail.

I eventually discovered the problem.

You need to set the [.NET Framework Launch Condition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xxyh2e6a%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

Here’s how to do it:

1. Right click on your deployment project in solution explorer.
   In the context menu, select *View -> Launch Conditions*
2. Under 'Version' choose '.NET Framework 4'

After rebuilding and deploying my setup file, everything worked fine."

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  Howver, your link is blocked at work. It is tagged as a malicious site for some reason. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: I was lucky enough to have that pants-cow virus on my site-
The above answer is a summary of what to do.

Comment: answer's a broken link.  Too bad, really needed this one.

Comment: Retrieved from Google cache:

1) Right click on your deployment project in solution explorer -> View -> Launch Conditions
2) Check properties of the .NET Framework node: under “Version” Choose .NET Framework 4
3) After rebuilding and deploying setup file, everything should be  fine.

PS: worked for me - thanks.

Comment: @alexjamesbrown Googled and surf too much but this hits Bulls-eye.. Perfect one shot working solution. Thats why +1.

Answer (score 11):

1. Click on the installer project, then go to Project>Properties.
2. Click on the Prerequisites button
3. Check the “Microsoft .NET Framework 4 (x86 and x64)” box and uncheck the previous version of the framework
4. Hit ok on the Prerequisites window and on the the properties window.
5. Right click on the installer project and go to View>Launch Conditions
6. Highlight the .NET Framework condition and update the following fields in the properties box
   a.  InstallURL : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa569263.aspx
   b.  Version: .NET Framework 4
7. Rebuild the installer

Comment: This does not solve the problem for me.  Everything is set to x64 and .NET Framework 4, and I still get this error.

Answer (score 7):

Those who still struggle, try the following [image]
 go to Custom action and  update the following to **true** in the property option
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for this post.  This has been driving me nuts forever.

Comment: This was the Answer for an x64 service that was erroring on install!